# InnoDB file_per_table storage release

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL DB set up with file_per_table. I know that InnoDB has a separate .ini for every table but I'm wondering if space is released when I drop a schema or when I drop a table. I know I get the space back when I drop a schema, I'm wondering if I drop a table will I reclaim the space?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you DROP or TRUNCATE a table that is stored in a separate .ibd tablespace file, the space is returned to the filesystem.

Demonstration:

```
$ df /var/lib/mysql
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb              33538048  14413988  19124060  43% /var/lib/mysql

$ sudo ls -lh /var/lib/mysql/data/imdb/name2.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 168M Apr 30 02:44 /var/lib/mysql/data/imdb/name2.ibd

mysql> drop table name2;

$ df /var/lib/mysql
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb              33538048  14151832  19386216  43% /var/lib/mysql
```

You can also OPTIMIZE an InnoDB table.  This will defragment the data and rebuild the indexes.  If you had a lot of wasted space in that file, then the optimized file will be smaller and the balance of space will be returned to the filesystem.